# SDWebImage not running

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, sdwebimage

This problem may be weird, but it is happening and I am not getting it.

I have just downloaded the code from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and try to run example project.

It is building successfully, but not running. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the Project scheme to SDWebImageDemo, and then Hit the Play/Run Button. It will work.

Comment: @Piyush okay. Not a problem. Thanks